# Send a meeting request using chilkat and delphi

Tags: delphi, chilkat, chilkat-email

Has anyone managed to send a meeting request using Chilkat and Delphi XE or any other method that would do the trick just as well?

Comment: What's Chilkat? How are the meeting requests supposed to be received? And I'm sure you don't actually want "any other method".

Comment: ChillKat url: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ And no, I'm not familiar with it, just good with Google. :-)

Comment: iCalendar / vCalandar (older format) over email is a common way to send meeting requests to users outside a given company. There are some Delphi components available and planned to be available that support this.